# How to have different work space (or canvas) in Apache Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I just started a project with Apache Nifi and I am new to this orchestration tool. From a Azure's standpoint in ADF, I would like to create a branch so that I can work on my own development or at least I want to create a separate pipeline in the workspace. In Apache Nifi, I have an user Interface that multiple people can work on. Even though the activities (or processors) in Nifi seems dependent unless specify otherwise, I would like to have my own work space as a separate canvas.
Is it possible to have multiple canvas as workspace in Apache Nifi on a single address ?

Kind regards,
Ken

Comment: just create a "process group" - it looks like a separate workspace

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a new process group with a unique name. Process Groups are a way to have a complete canvas to yourself that doesnt interfere with other canvases.

Answer (score 0):

using a "Process Group" is the easiest way.

if needed you can apply policies on each "Process Group".
for this you need to add some users (put them in a group) and create policies which fits to your needs. while creating the policies you can add users (and groups) to your policy to grant access, view, modify, ...

btw, you can route flowfiles IN and OUT of your "Process Group" using "Input Port" and "Output Port" (next to the processors in the menu bar of the NiFi canvas)